# Delphi 7 ProcessMemory Tlhelp32 Write string value

Tags: delphi, delphi-7, readprocessmemory

Does anyone know this problem when trying to write string value on **tlhelp32**?

**Raised exception class EInvalidPointer with message "Invalid pointer operation"**

Read Code:

```
function TPMemory.GetValues(ProcessID, Address: dword; VarType: integer; const Bits: Byte = 20;
    const Unicode: boolean = false): string;
var
    count: dword;

    bytes: byte;
    words: word;
    dwords: dword;
    floats: single;
    doubles: double;
    int64s: Int64;
    texts: pchar;
    unicodes: pwidechar;
    arrayOfBits: array of byte;

    j, PidHandle: integer;
    temp: string;
    check: boolean;
begin
    Result:= '????????';

    PidHandle:= OpenProcess(PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS,False,ProcessID);
    try
    case VarType of
        1 : begin // byte
            check:= readprocessmemory(PidHandle,pointer(Address),addr(bytes),1,count);
            if (not check) or (count=0) then result:='??' else
                Result:= inttostr(bytes);
        end;
        2 : begin // 2 bytes
            check:= readprocessmemory(PidHandle,pointer(Address),addr(words),2,count);
            if (not check) or (count=0) then result:='??' else
                Result:= inttostr(words);
        end;
        3 : begin // 3 bytes
            check:= readprocessmemory(PidHandle,pointer(Address),addr(dwords),3,count);
            if (not check) or (count=0) then result:='??' else
                Result:= inttostr(dwords);
        end;
        4,8 : begin // 4 bytes
            check:= readprocessmemory(PidHandle,pointer(Address),addr(dwords),4,count);
            if (not check) or (count=0) then result:='??' else
                Result:= inttostr(dwords);
        end;
        5 : begin    // float
            check:= readprocessmemory(PidHandle,pointer(Address),addr(floats),4,count);
            if (not check) or (count=0) then result:='??' else
                Result:= floattostr(floats);
        end;
        6 : begin   // double
            check:= readprocessmemory(PidHandle,pointer(Address),addr(doubles),8,count);
            if (not check) or (count=0) then result:='??' else
                Result:= floattostr(doubles);
        end;
        11 : begin    // text
            if Unicode then
            begin
                getmem(unicodes,Bits*2+2);
                check:=readprocessmemory(PidHandle,pointer(Address),unicodes,Bits*2,count);
                if (not check) or (count<Bits) then result:='??' else
                begin
                    unicodes[Bits]:=chr(0);
                    result:= unicodes;
                end;
                freemem(unicodes);
            end else
            begin
                getmem(texts,Bits+1);
                check:=readprocessmemory(PidHandle,pointer(Address),texts,Bits,count);
                if (not check) or (count<Bits) then result:='??' else
                begin
                    texts[Bits]:=chr(0);
                    result:= texts;
                end;
                freemem(texts);
            end;
        end;
        12 : begin //array of byte
            setlength(arrayOfBits,Bits);
            check:=readprocessmemory(PidHandle,pointer(Address),arrayOfBits,Bits,count);

            if (not check) or (count<Bits) then result:='??' else
            begin
                temp:='';
                for j:=0 to Bits-1 do
                    temp:=temp+IntToHex(arrayOfBits[j],2);//+' ';
                result:=temp;
            end;
            setlength(arrayOfBits,0);
        end;
        13 : begin //Int64
            check:=readprocessmemory(PidHandle,pointer(Address),addr(int64s),8,count);
            if (not check) or (count=0) then result:='??' else
            begin
                //if memrec[rec].ShowAsHex then
                //  result:='0x'+IntToHex(int64s,16)
                //else
                    result:=IntToStr(int64s);
            end;
        end;
    end;
    finally
        CloseHandle(PidHandle);
    end;
end;
```

Write Code:

```
procedure TPMemory.setValues(ProcessID,Address: dword; VarType: integer; Value: string;
  const unicode: boolean = false);
var
  bytes: byte;
  words: word;
  dwords: dword;
  singles: Single;
  doubles: Double;

  newValue, tempVal: string;
  newvalueSt: widestring;
  newValue6: int64;

  text: pchar;

  Written  : dword;
  err: integer;

  PidHandle: integer;
  original: dword;
resourcestring
  strNotValid = 'Value not valid!';
begin
  newValue:= Value;

  case VarType of
    1,2,3,4: begin
            val(newValue, newValue6, err);
            if err=0 then
            begin
              bytes  := byte(newValue6);
              words  := word(newValue6);
              dwords := dword(newValue6);
            end;
    end;
    5,6: begin
      val(newvalue,doubles,err);
      if err<>0 then
      begin
        if newvalue[err]=',' then newvalue[err]:='.'
        else
        if newvalue[err]='.' then newvalue[err]:=',';

        err:=0;
        val(newvalue,doubles,err);
      end;

      singles:= doubles;
    end;
    11: err:= 0;        
  end;

  if err>0 then raise Exception.Create(strNotValid);

  PidHandle:= OpenProcess(PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS,False,ProcessID);

  try

  VirtualProtectEx(pidhandle,  pointer(Address),SizeOf(newValue),PAGE_EXECUTE_READWRITE,original);

  case VarType of
    1: WriteProcessMemory(PidHandle, Pointer(Address), @bytes, 1, written);
    2: WriteProcessMemory(PidHandle, Pointer(Address), @words, 2, written);
    3: WriteProcessMemory(PidHandle, Pointer(Address), @dwords, 3, written);
    4: WriteProcessMemory(PidHandle, Pointer(Address), @dwords, 4, written);
    5: writeprocessmemory(PidHandle, Pointer(Address), addr(singles),4,written);
    6: writeprocessmemory(PidHandle, Pointer(Address), addr(doubles),8,written);
    11: begin
      Bytes:=0;
      Words:=0;
      if unicode then
      begin
        newvalueSt:=newvalue;
        writeprocessmemory(PidHandle,pointer(address),@newvalueSt[1],length(newvalueSt)*2,written);
        writeprocessmemory(PidHandle,pointer(address+length(newvalue)*2),addr(Words),2,written);
      end else
      begin
        getmem(text,length(newvalue));
        StrCopy(text, PChar(newvalue));
        writeprocessmemory(PidHandle,pointer(Address),text,length(newvalue),written);
        writeprocessmemory(PidHandle,pointer(address+length(newvalue)),addr(Bytes),1,written);
        freemem(text);
      end;
    end;
  end;

  VirtualProtectEx(pidhandle,  pointer(Address),SizeOf(newValue),original,written);

  finally
    CloseHandle(PidHandle);
  end;
end;
```

Calling:

```
Type
    TAppData = record
        Address: dword;
        Bit: integer;
        NewValue: string;
    end;

Var AppData: array [0..15] of TAppData;

Procedure TPMemory.WriteThis;
var 
    getVal: string;
    i: integer;
begin
    for i:= 0 to length(appData)-1 do
    begin
        getVal:= getValue(AppProcessID,appData[i].address,appData[i].bit);
        if not(getVal='') AND not(getVal[1]='?') then
            setValue(AppProcessID,appData[i].address,appData[i].bit,address,appData[i].newValue);
    end;
end;
```

When trying to write new value is different length of old value, like:

> Old value is "Does anyone know" then New value is "Does let me know about this"

And

> Old value is "Does anyone know" then New value is "" (empty value)

Give me "Invalid pointer operation" Error Message

Thanks

Comment: 1) Always check the results of all API calls for success/failure. 2) The size argument to `VirtualProtectEx` should be the actual byte-count, not just 1(one).

Comment: 3) your Unicode string patch suggests that the string is _followed_ by the length. That would be quite unusual - are you sure the length should not come first?

Comment: 1) I do check valid value in address each time before write to memory 2) Byte-count is variable or actual byte length of value

Comment: 3) Am not sure the Unicode code seem work, not even testing this before. My consent is normal string doesn't work, but seem work if i just added some text after old value. Like Does anyone know then Does anyone know about this, seems work

Comment: `SizeOf(Bytes)` here always evaluates to one.

Comment: Sorry that must SizeOf(newValue), just tried but it's same give me Invalid pointer operation.

Comment: You aren't checking return values, as you've been told. You first need to add proper error checking everywhere. Then you'll know more.